# Recursive function to change nested object in JSON to actual object

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to recreate a part of the `JSON.parse()` function that converts strings into nested objects.

ie

`recNest(JSON.stringify({b:{c:2}})) //--> {b:{c:2}}`

I'm thinking the best way to do this is recursion, and I think I'm getting close, but something is off. I've written this function so far:

```
function recNest(string,obj){

  console.log(string);

  if(string){
    let pS,pE,kS,kE,key;
    pS = string.indexOf('{') + 1;
    pE = string.lastIndexOf('}') ;

    kS = string.indexOf('"')+1;
    kE = string.indexOf(':')-1;
    key = string.substr(kS,kE - kS);
    console.log(string.substr(pS,pE-pS));

    obj[key] = recNest(string.substr(pS,pE-pS),obj);
  }
  return obj;
}
console.log(recNest(JSON.stringify({b:{c:2}}),{}));
```

If there's a way to do it without recursion, I'm open to that too.

Comment: The first `}` that appears right before `return obj;` may be causing issues if you're getting syntax errors

Comment: @m_callens typos in post resolved.

Comment: `return` stops the execution of the function. You've got a lot of dead code there.

Comment: *"that converts strings into nested functions"*: there is nothing in your code that converts things to functions.

Comment: I don't get why you want to write your own `parse` method. What is missing in the existing one? NB: parsing JSON is not easy. For instance, JSON does not have to have any braces. It can be an array, it can be a primitive value, it can have escape sequences, ...

Comment: @trincot for exercise purposes. I'm just rewriting this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a `JSON.parse` implementation is not that easy, as JSON can consist of braces (or not), square brackets (or not), strings with escape sequences, boolean and number primitives, ...

For the value you want to parse, your code has two problems:

1. The string value that is passed to the recursive call is no longer valid JSON, since it still contains the key of the disembodied string literal. It should only be the value part (after the colon).
2. There is no good return value at the end of the recursion, when the string value represents a primitive value: it is that value that the function should return.

You actually don't need to pass *obj* around: it should start from scratch anyway at each recursion level. The aggregation is done when the recursive call returns.

Here is your code with some commented corrections:

```
function recNest(string){ // No need for second argument
    let pS,pE,kS,kE,key,obj;

    // Always check the presence of the brace
    pS = string.indexOf('{') + 1;
    if(pS){ 
        pE = string.lastIndexOf('}') ;
        kS = string.indexOf('"')+1;
        kE = string.indexOf(':')-1;
        key = string.substr(kS, kE - kS);
        //Corrected substr arguments: only the value part should be passed
        obj = { [key]: recNest(string.substr(kE+2,pE-(kE+2))) };
    } else { // Assume it is a primitive value
        obj = string;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Note: extending this further so it will support more JSON texts is of course beyond the scope of this question. There are good libraries that parse JSON. For example [JSON 3](https://bestiejs.github.io/json3/).

Comment: This is perfect thank you. Thinking "recursively" is difficult for me so this is very much appreciated. Looking at that `polyfill` code you linked: I can see how `stringify` works in detail, but does it show how the `parse` method does? Is it just taking the inverse of `stringify` somehow?

Comment: You're welcome. I was to quick to link to the MDN site. It's polyfill just uses `eval` to mimic `JSON.parse`, which is not very helpful. I have included a reference to another library now.